# PathParam and FormDataParam

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client, enunciate

PathParam and FormDataParam are used within REST API but the docs from enunciate indicates 'path' for PathParam and 'formdata' for FormDataParam ?

I have 
include pattern="com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam"
include pattern="javax.ws.rs.PathParam"

in the enunciate.xml file.

Any suggestion ?

--->>> REST API:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response postStagedFileDataForm(
    FormDataMultiPart fdmp,
    @PathParam("spacecraftId") String spacecraftId,
    @FormDataParam("uploadedFile") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("uploadedFile") FormDataContentDisposition disposition,
    @FormDataParam("fileType") String fileType,
    @FormDataParam("group") String inputGroup,
    @FormDataParam("creationTime") String creationTime,
    @FormDataParam("checksum") String checksum,
    @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
throws IOException
```

--->>> docs in browser:

Parameters
name          description                type             default
spacecraftId (no documentation provided) path
uploadedInputStream (no documentation provided) formdata
disposition (no documentation provided) formdata
fileType (no documentation provided) formdata
inputGroup (no documentation provided) formdata
creationTime (no documentation provided) formdata
checksum (no documentation provided) formdata

By the way, how to display info into "description" field ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The docs are trying to describe how to use the parameters. So "spacecraftid" is a "path" parameter, and "fileType" is a "formdata" parameter.

To provide text in the description, use JavaDoc. See [format of a doc comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format).